# i3lock called by the i3-nagbar starts in the background

Tags: scripting, i3

I am trying to set up a lock script with the i3⁻nagbar command. The current code i have:

`i3-nagbar -b "lock" "i3lock" -b "shutdown" "shutdown -h 0"`

And while the shutdown button works, the lock button only flashes the i3lock screen and then gets back to the terminal. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure the reason why, but if you use `-B` instead of `-b` then it works  correctly. From the man page:

```
       -b, --button button action
           Create a button with text button. The action are the shell commands that will be executed by this button. Multiple buttons can be defined. Will launch the shell commands inside a terminal emulator, using i3-sensible-terminal.

       -B, --button-no-terminal button action
           Same as above, but will execute the shell commands directly, without launching a terminal emulator.
```

My command that works is:

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+e exec "i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'You pressed the exit shortcut. Do you really want to exit i3? This will end your X session.' -b 'Yes, exit i3' 'i3-msg exit' -B 'Lock Screen' 'i3lock -c 000000'"
```